# Could not apply delete function to images in showFiles and previousFile function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, frontend, dropzone.js

I have a rent detail page developed using reactjs which shows the detail of specific rent. There is an edit button on the page too and it is displayed to only to that user who has registered it. For editing i wanted to fetch previous stored data of that rent to input boxes and also images just below an image upload box. I could fetch rental data to the input boxes by calling **this.props.ownerName** to the defaultValue and also could fetch the uploaded images in **previousFile()** but could not create delete function by using delete icon on each images and also could not post previously uploaded images along with images that are further added to the server. I have used **react-dropzone**(https://github.com/okonet/react-dropzone) for image upload. Could anyone please help me?

**code on image upload**

```
 let image = [];
 class RenderPhotos extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = {
            files: []
        };
    }

    onDrop(files) {
      console.log('Received files: ', files);
      this.setState({
          files: files
      });

      image = new FormData(files);
      $.each(files,function(i,file){
        image.append('image',file);
      });

    }

    previousFile(){
      console.log('this.props.image', this.props.image);
      return(
          <ul className="gallery">
            {
             _.map(this.props.image, (image,idx) => {
                      return(
                          <li className="col-md-3" key={idx}>
                             <img src={image.image} key={image.id} className="img-fluid img-rounded" />
                          </li>
                        )
                    })
            }
          </ul>
        )
    }

    showFiles() {
        const { files } = this.state;
        if (!files.length) {
            return null;
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>Dropped files: </h3>
                <ul className="gallery">
                    {
                        _.map(files, (file, idx) => {
                            return (
                                <li className="col-md-3" key={idx}>
                                    <img src={file.preview} width={200}/>
                                    <div>{file.name}</div>
                                </li>
                            )
                        })

                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }

    render() {
      return (
           <div>
                <h3 className="formHeadingh3">Photos can bring your space to life</h3>
                <p>Add photos of spaces to give more insight of your space </p>
                <hr/>
                <div className="col-md-12">
                <form method="POST" encType="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="{{ csrf_token }}"/>
                  <Dropzone onDrop={this.onDrop.bind(this)}
                          style={style}
                          activeStyle={activeStyle}
                          accept="image/*">
                    Try dropping some files here, or click to select files to upload.
                </Dropzone>
              </form>
                { this.previousFile() }
                { this.showFiles() }

              </div>
              <div className="row continueBtn text-right">
                    <button className="btn how-it-works pull-left" onClick={this.props.previousStep.bind(this)}><i className="fa fa-hand-o-left"></i></button>
                    <button className="btn how-it-works pull-right" onClick={this.nextStep.bind(this)}><i className="fa fa-floppy-o"></i></button>
               </div>
            </div>

      );
    }
```

while uploading images the images preview are shown from **showFiles()** and previously uploaded images are fetched through **previousFile()**